# The ssl module in Python is not available

Tags: python, ubuntu, openssl, buildozer

i am trying to use bulldozer on a python application but when i run buildozer android debug i get the following error (i am on ubuntu-22.04.3 (virtual machine) and python 3.12):

```
running python3 -m venv venv
[INFO]:    Upgrade pip to latest version
[DEBUG]:   -> running bash -c source venv/bin/activate && pip install -U pip
[DEBUG]:        Ignoring "sys._home = value" override
[DEBUG]:        WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
[DEBUG]:        Requirement already satisfied: pip in ./venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages (23.2.1)
[DEBUG]:        WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
```

I tried just about every solution on the internet with no sucesse, some of the things i tried:

1-

run sudo apt install libssl-dev libncurses5-dev libsqlite3-dev libreadline-dev libtk8.6 libgdm-dev libdb4o-cil-dev libpcap-dev

2-

./configure
make
sudo make install

3-

installing openssl from "dreamhost"
install python and ./configure --with-openssl=/home/username/openssl

Comment: A missing `ssl` module usually means that (a) you built Python from source and (b) that it couldn't find the ssl libraries or header files at build time. Consider using a packaged version rather than building from source. If you must build from source,  inspect the output of the entire process for errors or other status information related to openssl.